# What is the difference between variable post-increment/decrement and pre-increment/decrement in bash?

Tags: bash

**ARITHMETIC EVALUATION** section in bash manual lists following operators among others:

```
   id++ id--
          variable post-increment and post-decrement
   ++id --id
          variable pre-increment and pre-decrement
```

As I understand, `++x` and `--xx` increase or decrease the variable before other operations are performed? For example `x++`:

```
$ x=5; echo $(( ++x / 2 ))
3
$ x=5; echo $(( x++ / 2 ))
2
$
```

However, when are `x++` and `x--` useful? And in general what is the difference between variable post-increment/decrement and pre-increment/decrement in bash?

Comment: You already identified the difference, so what is the question here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from [Increment and decrement operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Increment_and_decrement_operators):

> In languages that support both versions of the operators, the
>   *pre*-increment and *pre*-decrement operators increment (or decrement) their operand by 1, and the value of the expression is the resulting
>   incremented (or decremented) value. In contrast, the *post*-increment
>   and *post*-decrement operators increase (or decrease) the value of
>   their operand by 1, but the value of the expression is the operand's
>   original value *prior* to the increment (or decrement) operation.

So, you'll find:

```
$ x=5; echo $(( x++ / 2 ))
2
$ echo ${x}                     // The effect of post-increment is visible here
3
```

Answer (score 1):

Both post-ops and pre-ops change (increase/decrease) value of the variable.

The difference is what they evaluate to: pre-ops evaluate to the value of the variable *after* the change, and post-ops - to the value *before* the change.

When the evaluated value isn't used, there is no difference. I.e. these two lines have the same effect:

```
((x++))
((++x))
```

Both pre-ops and post-ops are used to remove the need for an explicit assignment. I.e. make code shorter. So, instead of writing this:

```
x=$((x + 1))
y=$((x * 5))
```

You can write this:

```
y=$((++x * 5))
```

Conversely, instead of this:

```
y=$((x * 5))
x=$((x + 1))
```

You can write this:

```
y=$((x++ * 5))
```

Most often these operations are used in loop bodies and loop control expressions.